# How do you play a character stripped of alignment?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, roleplaying, alignment

We are playing a game that doesn't rely too heavily on alignment except for the paladin and that we are on a campaign to stop demonic forces, so we are encountering lots of chaotic-evil outsiders.  But other than these things, we are just generally good adventurers trying to stop the baddies. But in the game, my neutral good character was asked by a witch type npc, "what would you sacrifice for power?"  We were fairly low level,  and didn't have any especially precious items and such to give up, so I offered my morals. The GM liked this idea and said I no longer had an alignment. Not neutral, not evil, not chaotic, just no alignment. 
This sounded like a fun thing, and I don't want to be unfair to the barbarian that gave up his anger (the GM took this to mean no more rage powers), and just play with out effects to my character.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a moment to check out the [tour] and the [help] to get an idea of how things work.

Answer (score 13):

Come up with that yourself, or consult your group for assistance in working out what it should mean. You and your party are (in-game or at the table) coming across something new and exciting in the world: an individual who transcends alignment. It's in your power to determine where you go from here.

There's no precedent for this in Pathfinder that I'm aware of, or guidance on how to handle it. There's guidance on removing alignment *completely* from Pathfinder, but a single individual in a world of alignment is another matter altogether. You're on your own! Your group came up with something custom, so follow through and customise what it means.

There are two things impacted here for your character's personality, because alignment has two purposes in roleplaying.

- First, it represents the sides in a cosmic war ([originally](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/19543/1204) law vs chaos, later also good vs evil). Your character now has no side, they're beyond the war.
- Second, it represents your character's personality (but it [never did a very good job of that](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/32032/1204), because most nontrivial acts can be justified as belonging to many different alignments). Their personality is no longer bound to follow any alignment, not even Neutral — this is your opportunity to flesh out what this means.

*Personally,* your best option may be to look to Buddha, or sages from other religions focused on enlightenment, for inspiration. You're now playing an individual who has become unbound from life's concerns, which is more or less enlightenment. (That doesn't mean you can't perform good acts or evil acts — any act is going to be arguably aligned in some ways — but you are no longer bound to particular types of acts.)

Comment: Love the enlightenment idea.